# RGB/HEX to Colormap Value

Tags: colors, rgb, colormap, color-mapping

I would like to convert RGB/HEX colors to a corresponding (normalized) numeric value given a specific colormap. There are many utilities that can do the forward  operation (i.e. map a set of normalized values to RGB/HEX colors using a colormap), but I haven't been able to find any carry out the reverse.

Forward:

```
> import matplotlib.cm as cm
> cm.viridis([.2, .4, .6, .8, 1])

array([[ 0.253935,  0.265254,  0.529983,  1.      ],
       [ 0.163625,  0.471133,  0.558148,  1.      ],
       [ 0.134692,  0.658636,  0.517649,  1.      ],
       [ 0.477504,  0.821444,  0.318195,  1.      ],
       [ 0.993248,  0.906157,  0.143936,  1.      ]])
```

How can I get from `[ 0.253935,  0.265254,  0.529983,  1.      ]` to `0.2`, of course, knowing that these come from  `viridis`?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example using Matlab implementation (explain the principle of reverse mapping).

In case you are looking for Python implementation, add Python tag to your question.

Here is my code sample (explanations are within comments):

```matlab
array = [0.253935,  0.265254,  0.529983,  1;
         0.163625,  0.471133,  0.558148,  1;
         0.134692,  0.658636,  0.517649,  1;
         0.477504,  0.821444,  0.318195,  1;
         0.993248,  0.906157,  0.143936,  1];

%c is the RGB value (value is assumed to exist in array).
c = [0.253935,  0.265254,  0.529983,  1];

%B is the mapped value.
B = [.2, .4, .6, .8, 1];

%1 Remove the alpha channel (assume all alpha values equal 1):
A = array(:, 1:3);

%2. Convert from normalized value in range [0, 1] to fixed point values in range [0, 255].
%(assume each color channel is a byte).
A = round(A*255);

%3. Convert RGB triple to single fixed point value (24 bits integer).
%   Remark: For best performance, you can create a Look Up Table (16MBytes look up table that maps all possible combinations).
%   Remark: You can also create a Dictionary.
A = A(:,1) + A(:,2)*2^8 + A(:,3)*2^16;

%4. Do the same conversion for c:
c = round(c*255);
c = c(1)+c(2)*2^8+c(3)*2^16;

%5. Find index of c in A:
%   Remark: In case A is sorted, you can use binary search.
%   Remark: In case A is Look Up Table (or dictionary), you can use something like idx = A(c).
idx = find(A == c);

%6. The result is B in place idx:
reverse_val = B(idx)
```

Result:

```
reverse_val =

    0.2000
```

---

In Python you can probably find a shortcut like: converting to string, build a dictionary (from string to index or to value)...